# Use `href` attribute as CSS background-image

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML which I cannot modify. There is a CSS file that I can. Is there a way to get the href value/attribute and use it as CSS background-image?

I need something like:

```
    background-image: url(href value);
```

Is that possible? The href value is the result of a search, so it's not always the same.

```
<tr class="trdata1">
    <td class="file">
        <span class="nobr">
            <nobr>
                <a href="/C/.../.../image.jpg">
                    <img class="icon" src="/file.gif" alt="">$image.jpg
                </a>
            </nobr>
        </span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You can do this by using javascript or jQuery

Comment: @AbhishekPandey - How would it be possible to use javascript without it being inside the html script tags and the results of javascript being on the existing html page?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do it with pure CSS, you will have to use Javascript for that. E.g. with jQuery:

```
$('.your-element').css(
  'background-image', 'url(' + $('.trdata1 > .file a').attr('href') + ')'
);
```

Comment: How am I gonna iclude the javascript/jQuery since I cant modify the html?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the attribute of that hyperlink, and apply it to the element with jquery.

```
var imgHref = $(".nobr nobr a").attr("href");
$(".imageBg").css('background-image','url('+imgHref+')');
```

[working example](https://jsfiddle.net/urd6rvts/2/)

Note: Please ensure the class names are unique

Comment: I want something to be applied to the existing page without modifying the html since its not possible. The only thing that I can modify is the CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it dynamically with pure CSS.

In pure CSS you can do it only statically:

```
your-selector {
    background-image: url("static-value");
}
```